# Triggers para acualizar la taba current_stock de productos

Tags: sql, trigger, update

Sea el siguiente enunciado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y las relaciones de las bases de datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta espefica es para el tercer punto que es la operacion de Update. Como obtengo la cantidad anterior si estoy usando un triger After con la tabla factura_det(faturas detalles)?

Cuando ocurre una acutalizacion del campo cantidad de un registro de factura_det, se ejecutará despues(after)y no antes la sentencia Sql que esta dentro del trigger, por lo que el campo cantidad de facturas_det va a estar ya cambiado, y lo mismo la tabla insertad que contiene datos ya actualizados(ambas no van a tener la cantidad anterior).

Como puedo recuperar esa cantidad anterior para actualizar correctamente la tabla Current_Stock y asi  hacer bien el tercer punto del Update del enunciado.

Paso lo que he hecho hasta ahora de código. Hice los dos puntos la operacion Insert y Delete, pero me falta el tercer punto Update en donde tengo la duda.
Si me pueden ayudar. Desde ya gracias.

```
CREATE TABLE CURRENT_STOCK (
PRODUCTO_COD INT PRIMARY KEY,
CANTIDAD_ACTUAL INT,
CREATEDUPDATE DATETIME NOT NULL)

CREATE TRIGGER InsersUpDele ON facturasDet 
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE AS 


IF SELECT (COUNT (1) FROM DELETED) > 0
    BEGIN 
        SET @ACCION = 'DELETED'
    END
IF SELECT (COUNT (1) FROM INSERTED) > 0
    BEGIN 
        SET @ACCION = 'INSERTED'
    END


BEGIN
    --INSERCION
    IF @ACCION = 'INSERTED'
        BEGIN
        IF NOT exists (select * from inserted A  inner join CURRENT_STOCK B ON B.PRODUCTO_COD = @PRODUCTO_COD  )        

            INSERT INTO CURRENT_STOCK(PRODUCTO_COD,CANTIDAD_ACTUAL, FECHA) VALUE(SELECT PRODUCTO_ COD , "0" + CANTIDAD, FECHA_EMISION FROM INSERTED I INNER JOIN FACTURAS F  ON I.FACTURA_NUM = F.FACTURA_NUM)
        ELSE
            UPDATE CURRENT_STOCK SET  C.CANTIDAD_ACUAL = C.CANTIDAD_ACUAL- I.CANTIDAD, C.FECHA= F.FECHA_EMISION FROM CURRENT_STOCK C INNER JOIN 
                        INSERTED I ON C.PRODUCTO_COD = I.PRODUCTO_COD INNER JOIN FACTURAS F ON I.FACTURA_NUM = F.FACTURA_NUM)
                        WHERRE C. PRODUCTO_COD = I.PRODUCTO_COD
    --DELETE 
    ELSE
           BEGIN
           UPDATE CURRENT_STOCK SET C.CANTIDAD_ACTUAL =  C.ANTIDAD_ACTUAL + I.CANTIDAD, CREATEDUPDATE = F.FECHA EMISION FROM  CURRENT_STOCK C INNER JOIN
               INSERTED I ON C.PRODUCTO_COD = I.PRODUCTO_COD INNER JOIN FACTURAS F ON I.FACTURA_NUM = F.FACTURA_NUM)
               WHERE C.PRODUCTO_COD = I.PRODUCTO_COD
           END
    END
 
    --UPDATE
```

Comment: Pablo, llevas en el sitio casi dos años y sabes cómo funciona. El código como texto, no como imagen, por favor.

Comment: Si disculpe, si lo sabia pero estaba tan apurado que  introduje el código como imagen y no como texto.  Si por esas me puede ayudar en este ejercicio. Gracias

Comment: La validación de los ifs es incorrecta. Una update también tendrá al menos un registro en `Inserted`. La solución pasa por mezclar `inserted` con `deleted`. Si `deleted` no tiene filas, entonces es insertar. Si tiene filas es actualizar. Para borrar al contrario, `Deleted` con `Inserted`. Si `inserted` no tiene filas, es borrado. Por tanto, en el manejo de las pseudotablas `inserted` y `deleted`, donde en inserted tienes los "nuevos valores" y en deleted los "viejos valores" está la solución al ejercicio para el update.

Comment: Has puesto la etiqueta sql, pero sin especificar el motor. Por la sintaxis, a mi me parece que es Sql Server y si es así, la sentencia de inserción no es correcta tampoco.  No deberías de usar `value` sino directamente y sin paréntesis, la select. Teniendo en cuenta que el if te sobra y que deberías de hacer un `left join` contra `deleted` y aplicar algo como `Where deleted.facturaNum is null`

Comment: Gracias Javier por tu respuesta.  Pero a la linea de abajo a que te referis. Porque hacer Where deleted.facturaNum is nulLL, porque debo encontrar mas bien la factura para obtener el campo fecha emision